# how to break ggplot code into multiple lines in rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Maybe a dumb question: How can we break ggplot code into multiple lines, each line ended with `+`?

I tried to do that in rstudio editor, but it does not work.

Comment: Why does hitting `Enter` after each `+` not work? Are you looking for an automated solution that re-flows after you have typed it in?

Comment: ok, I got it. I actually hit enter Before each +. That did not work...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but I'll offer a suggestion.  When working with long ggplot, dplyr or other statements in rstudio, I structure the lines:

```
results = (dcsv
  %>% mutate(sdisagree_pct = strongly_disagree / n_resp * 100)
#  %>% select( Item,sdisagree_pct:sagree_pct)
  %>% rename( `Strongly disagree` = sdisagree_pct,
              `Disagree` = disagree_pct,
              `Neutral` = neutral_pct,
              `Agree` = agree_pct,
              `Strongly agree` = sagree_pct
              )
)
```

Note the parentheses wrapping the entire multiline statement.  The parenthesis force R to read the multiple lines regardless of where the operator is located in the line.  Also note that I put the `%>%` operator at the beginning of each line.  With the operator at the beginning of the line, I'm able to comment out `#` specific lines for testing.  The same structure works with a `+` operator for ggplot.